# PHP Request URL after the first level

Tags: php, regex, trim

I'm trying to request the whole URL path after the first folder.

```
https://example.com/uk/<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>
```

With the above code, I'm getting duplicate /uk/ directory, any way to trim that?

Sorry about that let me clarify, im trying to implement hreflang code on my site through php, otherwise i would have to do manually on 500 pages.

The hreflang I'm trying to implement is for UK and USA which i have separate directories to target the specific countries.

Not hard-coding the UK in the URL would give me consistent the same URL i need to find a way around so i can get something similar to this:

Code:

```
https://example.com/uk/<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>
https://example.com/us/<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>
```

Results:

```
https://example.com/uk/international-targeting
https://example.com/us/international-targeting
```

Comment: show me the Code

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is everything after your domain and tld.

Comment: Are you working within a framework or a CMS platform? This is a common problem, and many of the popular frameworks and CMSes have already worked it out and have defined ways of doing it.

Comment: I am working on a wordpress platform, trying to setup my international audience. As far as im aware of there is no way to mass implement hreflang with plugins or anything except php.

Comment: Have you tried [HREFLANG Tags Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hreflang-tags-by-dcgws/) or [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly this might be a solution
It might not be the cleanest way to do things but I think [Substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) should work.

It'll look something like this:

```
https://example.com/uk/<?php echo substr('$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]' , 4);?>
```

That should remove the first 4 character from `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: Thanks Mac sorry my bad i didnt specify the issue, actually i will need it to work with uk, us and / (root). I updated my post, thanks for your help tho!

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives you everything after your domain and tld. For example `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in `example.com/test` will yield `/test`.

Knowing this, you can do remove the first part of your string like this:
    # Your url
    $url = 'http://example.com/uk/test/some/more';

```
# Fetch the uri
//$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request_uri ='/uk/test/some/more';

# Split the uri into an array
$request_uri_array = explode('/', $request_uri);

# Unset `uk`, which is the second element in the array
unset($request_uri_array[1]);

# Re-assemble the array into a string
$fixed_uri = implode('/', $request_uri_array);

echo $fixed_uri;
```

Note that this is just an example approach